# StrutsRequestWrapper cannot case to MultiPartRequestWrapper

Tags: java, struts2, upload

I've problemed by this question,and wish to be solved by you,much thanks,and the question like this:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsRequestWrapper cannot be cast to org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.multipart.MultiPartRequestWrapper 
org.apache.jsp.admin.upload_jsp._jspService(upload_jsp.java:99) 
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70) 
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717) 
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:386) 
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313) 
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260) 
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717) 
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ActionContextCleanUp.doFilter(ActionContextCleanUp.java:102) 
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:88)
```

add:
In my local environment,the upload function all is OK，but when I deploy it on server,It's wrong,my local environment like this:
windows xp,32 bit jdk 1.6,tomcat 6.0
server environment like this:
windows server 2003,32 bit jdk1.6,tomcat 6.0
and any other is the same

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your full code implementation, we can't able to help you to fix the issue. based on the exception you posted i think the problem is just that, you need to add the following parameter inside your html form.

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

and then the cast should work. If it doesn't work Use the built-in file upload capabilities of Struts 2; there's no reason to access the request manually.

Here's that link again:

http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/how-do-we-upload-files.html